# Отображение всплывающего окна до загрузки страницы

Tags: php, javascript

Есть сайт из двух страниц:
форма с авторизацией/регистрацией и страница с основным контентом.
При вводе корректной пары логин/пароль, делаю

```
sessionStorage.setItem('logged', 'yes');    
window.location = "mainpage/index.php";
```

При загрузки страницы с основным контентом сравниваю параметр сессии с нужным значением, если оно нужное (yes), то всё норм, сайт показывается.

```
<?php
echo <<<END
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='css/sweetalert2.min.css'>
    <script src="js/sweetalert2.all.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            if (sessionStorage.getItem("logged") != 'yes') {
                swal({
                    html: "<b>Вы не авторизованы в системе.<b><br><b>Сейчас вы будете перенаправлены на страницу авторизации!<b>",
                    type: 'error',
                }).then(function() {
                        window.location = "../index.php";
                });
            }
        })
    </script>
END;
?>
```

Однако если без авторизации попытаться вручную перейти на вторую страницу, то он показывает все элементы, потом отрабатывает if, выводит swal и делает редирект.
Осознаю, что так ка это js скрипт, он ждет загрузки всей страницы.

Есть ли вариант этого избежать? И сперва отрабатывать if, а потом если нужно отрисовать элементы.

Comment: А вы не думали редиректить обратно со стороны сервера? Обойти `window.location` как пальцем щелкнуть.

Comment: @Manitikyl, если я правильно понимаю, то вы говорите про редирект через хедер? Пробовал, ничего не меняется. 
У меня основная задача - показать swal, не показывая остальной контент, и потом сделать редирект.

Answer (score 0):

```
    //$(document).ready(function() {
        if (sessionStorage.getItem("logged") != 'yes') {
            document.addEventListener("readystatechange", function() {
              var content = document.querySelector("селектор для элемента, внутри которого находится весь контент, который Вы не хотите показывать");
              if (content)
                 content.style.display = "none";
            });
            swal({
                html: "<b>Вы не авторизованы в системе.<b><br><b>Сейчас вы будете перенаправлены на страницу авторизации!<b>",
                type: 'error',
            }).then(function() {
                    window.location = "../index.php";
            });
        }
    //})
```

Comment: проблема осталась. 
Добавлю, что сам код в файле login.php. И я его через include_once до тега <html> подключаю.

Comment: Со вторым вариантам уже сам игрался. На деле выходит - при переходе на страницу буквально на долю секунды видны элементы, потом они скрываются, но при этом не swal, не window.location уже не отрабатывают. 
Когда вместо swal вставляешь alert - все круто, работает так, как задумано.

Comment: всё так же, содержимое body скрывается, swal и редирект не отрабатываются

Comment: в таком случае происходит - загрузка элементов, появление окна - применение свойства display (часть элементов пропадает), и лишь потом редирект.